# Bootstrap 3 tool tips and jquery validation on form field causing problems

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, tooltip, jquery-validation-engine

I have been using jquery validation with custom rules (some with the help of you). However, I am trying to now add tool tips to the form fields with validation (no the error is not being showed in a tool tip).

When I have just the validation, the message is added and removed properly. However, when I add a tool tip to the form field, the text-error p tag remains even after you appease the validation rule.

**Validation rule**

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("a2format", function (val, el, params) {
    var a2check = true;
    var a2size = $("#alias2").val().length;
    if (a2size == 0) {
        a2check = true;
    } else if (val.charAt(0) == "2" ) {
        a2check = true;
    } else {
        a2check = false;
    }
    return a2check;
},"Your dial in code needs to start with  the number 2.");
```

**Adding tool tip to field**

```
$('input[id=alias2]').tooltip({'trigger':'focus', 'placement': 'top', 'title': 'To set up a Custom Dial In Code please start with a 2'});
```

**Adding the validation to the fields**

```
$("#alias1, #alias2").change(function() {
    var aliasChk = jQuery.extend(validationPluginDefaults, {
        rules: {
            alias1:{
                validateAlias: true,
                aliasFormat: true
            },
            alias2:{
                a2format: true
            }
        }
    });

    $("#mtg_form").validate(aliasChk);

    if ($("#mtg_form").valid()) {
        $("#updateMtg_btn").prop("disabled", false);        
    } else {
        $("#updateMtg_btn").prop("disabled", true);
    }   
});
```

**HTML for the field**

```
<div>   
    <label class="mtgFormLabel" for="alias2" id="alias2Label">Custom Dial In Code <span class="grayText smallText">(optional)</span>:</label> 
    <input type="text" class="noResize form-control input-md" id="alias2" name="alias2" maxlength="300" style="width: 98%" placeholder="Please enter a numeric value">              
</div>
```